# How can i "crop" the svg to fit the shape of the parent?

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

How can i "crop" the svg filter to fit the shape of the parent?

Right now I have a div as a circle, with an svg in it. But the svg filter creates an rectangel.

Edit: I tried to implement a wrapping div with border-radius:100% as suggested below, but then it removes the blur.

[original codepen](https://codepen.io/emmanders/pen/RwZjEeX)

[updated codepen with wrapping div](https://codepen.io/emmanders/pen/yLoPZqR)

```css
svg{
  width:100%; 
  height: 100%;  

}
.custom-cursor {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
    background-image: conic-gradient( cyan, magenta, yellow, cyan); 
  filter: blur(5px) url("#blur-plus-grain");
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-cursor">
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <filter id="blur-plus-grain">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.8" result="blur" />
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="26" baseFrequency="40" stitchTiles="stitch" result="grain" />
      <feComposite operator="in" in="blur" in2="grain" />
    </filter>
    <circle fill="transparent" r="10" cx="50%" cy="50%" filter="url(#blur-plus-grain)" />
  </svg>

</div>
```

[image: without the filter]

[image: with filter]

Comment: Hi, I looked at your code pen and put the div dimensions to 200px to see what was happening better. The whole thing was circular. Then I removed the SVG which seemed to make no difference. Could you describe more what the problem is? It may be that down at 20px dimensions you are getting edge effects - there aren't many pixels to make things look properly round.

Answer (score 1):

You apply the svg noise-blur filter to your round gradient-filled div.
But there is still a css box context.

You actually need some padding to provide enough 'canvas' area.
Otherwise any kind of blur might exceed for div elements boundaries:

[image: cropped blur area]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.custom-cursor-clip {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding:2%;
  filter: url("#blur-plus-grain");
}
.custom-cursor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: conic-gradient(from 20deg, #003399, #74b4da, #e0bbd9);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-cursor-clip">
  <div class="custom-cursor">
    <svg preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <filter id="blur-plus-grain">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4" result="blur" />
        <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="26" baseFrequency="40" stitchTiles="stitch" result="grain" />
        <feComposite operator="in" in="blur" in2="grain" />
      </filter>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
Essentially you apply the conic gradient to the inner div.
The wrapping/outer div provides some padding as well as the svg-filter.

**Edit 2:**

You might also use the `<foreignObject>` element for a more self-contained svg img asset:

```html
    <svg  width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <style>
        .conicGradient{
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          border-radius: 100%;
          background-image: conic-gradient(from 20deg, #003399, #74b4da, #e0bbd9);
        }
      </style>
      <filter id="blur-plus-grain" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4" result="blur" />
        <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="26" baseFrequency="40" stitchTiles="stitch" result="grain" />
        <feComposite operator="in" in="blur" in2="grain" />
      </filter>  
      <foreignObject filter="url(#blur-plus-grain)" 
      x="10" y="10" width="80" height="80">
        <div class="conicGradient" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ></div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
```

However, you still need some sort of padding/inner offset to prevent undesired cropping.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Updated the codepen. However, the blur on the edges disappear with this solution. =(

Comment: It looks good in my browser (Chrome/Win10).

Comment: @Emma Andersson: I've added another example code, that might be better suited.